# Excel: Custom a conditional format rule: if cells in colums C are not empty, then

Tags: excel

I am trying to use a custom conditional format rule: if cells in column C are not empty, then color all other cells of the same line in green.

What should I enter in the cell of the Conditional Format Rule option? (http://hpics.li/9492511)

Should I use something like "not blank"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming headers are in row 1 and actual data starts in row 2, use this conditional format formula:

```
=AND($C2<>"",COLUMN(A2)<>3)
```

Apply it to the range that contains your data, in this example, I applied it to range $A$2:$E$21 and here is an image of what the result would look like:

[image: tigeravatar example for Maud]

Comment: Thank you this worked and was very easy once you gave me the formula :)

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting only works for the same cell, unfortunately.
You can use VBA to check the cell, and format other ones based on that formatting.

```
for(i = 0 to NUM_ROWS)
    if cells(i,3).value = ""
        for(j = 0 to NUM_COLS)
            cells(i,j).Interior.Color = RGB(33, 173, 28)
        next
    end if
 next
```

I haven't tested it, but it should be pretty close.

Comment: It's incredibly useful, but a bit overkill for this example. @tigeravatar had the better answer, and deserves his check mark :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it looks like you could do this with conditional formatting. 
for your formula you'd want

`$C1 = ""`

This *should* work for every value.